# Convergence of sequences of differences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ be a sequence of numbers such that for all $p \in \mathbb N$ the difference $a_{n+p}-a_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity. What can we say about the convergence of $a_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $a_n$ need not converge. Consider $a_n=\sqrt n$.

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence is bounded, then the sequence will be convergent.

Proof:
Because the sequence is bounded, then there exist convergent subsequence {$a_{b_j}$},{$b_j$} is the subsequence number of {$a_{i}$}.
 
Further more, any number of the sequence between $a_{b_j}$ and $a_{b_{j+1}}$. will be limited to any given $\epsilon$. Because $a_{b_j}$ - $a_{b_j + k}$ is convergent(0 $\leq$ k $\leq$  $b_{j+1}$ ).

Answer (score 0):

As another example,

$\;\;\;a_n=\ln n$ satisfies this condition, yet diverges.